# Incompatible postgis 2.1 for postgresql 9.3.3 homebrew os x 10.10

Tags: postgresql, osx-yosemite, postgis

I have upgraded from OS X 10.9 to 10.10 Yosemite. I was running postgresql 9.3.3 with postgis 2.1. I did not do a pgdump before upgrading to OS X 10.10 (I know, I know, kill me...) but I have the original data directory. I did a brew install postgresql and got 9.4.4. So I installed Postgresql 9.3.9 (the only 9.3 version I could find) with Homebrew. Also brew install postgis. I then got a version 2.1 Postgis for Postgresql 9.4.4. I tried to install postgis20 but that does not work with my database.

When I start Postgresql 9.3.3 I can see all my databases but when I browse I get the error:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
```

I tried to link to posts-2.1 in the $libdir directory but then I get this message:

```
ERROR:  incompatible library     "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql93/9.3.9/lib/postgis-2.1.so": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 9.3, library is version 9.4.
```

So obviously I need a postgis-2.1 for Postgresql 9.3 but I don't know how to fix that.

If I try to run a pg_dumpall I get this error (obvious I guess):

```
➜ ./pg_dumpall >> old_backup.sql                                                                                             
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "darwin_test" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so": dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so, 10): Symbol not found: _json_tokener_errors
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjson-c.2.dylib
in /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so
```

So how do I get postgis-2.1 to work again with postgresql 9.3.3?
In homebrew I only find a postgis-2.1 for postgresql94.

Answer (score 2):

Use `brew edit postgis` to change the `postgresql` references to `postgresql93` in the install script and then run `brew install postgis`. You might also have to link/unlink postgresql using `brew link postgresql93` or `brew unlink postgresql`.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure this would work but I did in fact do an install of PostgreSQL 9.3.9 and Postgis 2.1 from `http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres`. The data catalog worked fine with the "original" versions. Then I did a backup/export and installed PostgreSQL 9.4 and Postgis with `brew install`

Comment: @Joey, you mentioned updating references to `postgresql` in the formula file. Could you be more explicit about where the references are?

Comment: You can grep the file for `postgresql` to locate the references to replace with `postgresql93`